# Setting up laravel Project into Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: laravel, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a problem setting up Laravel Project into my Nginx Reverse Proxy

I had proxy pass my laravel project into nginx reverse-proxy.conf

Here is my configuration in reverse-proxy.conf

```
location ^~ "/pys/" {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
                proxy_pass http://XXX.XX.X.X:1228/;
        }
```

When I run into my browser, with my url **XXX.XXX.X.XX/pys** it will redirect to login page,
after entering the credentials, the page returns **404 not found** and with the URL of **XXX.XXX.X.XX** only and all the routes in Laravel Project is affected.

Is there any possibility that I can fix the URL with **/pys** ?

Thank you